# Spark2.3 - SQL fetch before and later records of a String

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have nearly 2 million records, need to fetch 2000 records based on a search text condition.

For example:
if search text is 'error', it should return, 1000 records before the occurrence of 'error' and 1000 records after occurrence of 'error' text, so total 2000 records.

Please suggest most crisp and efficient solution.

*I have the following dataframe:*

```
+-----+---+-----+----------+
|index|  X|label|      date|
+-----+---+-----+----------+
|    1|  1|    A|2017-01-01|
|    2|  3|    B|2017-01-02|
|    3|  5|    C|2017-01-03|
|    4|  7|    D|2017-01-04|
|    5|  7|    E|2017-01-04|
|    6|  7|    F|2017-01-04|
|    7|  7|    G|2017-01-04|
|    8|  7|    H|2017-01-04|
|    9|  7|    I|2017-01-04|
|   10|  7|    J|2017-01-04|
+-----+---+-----+----------+
```

if input search text(label column) is 'F' and pre and post count is 2

*Desired output:*

```
+-----+---+-----+----------+
|index|  X|label|      date|
+-----+---+-----+----------+
|    4|  7|    D|2017-01-04|
|    4|  7|    E|2017-01-04|
|    4|  7|    F|2017-01-04|
|    4|  7|    G|2017-01-04|
|    4|  7|    H|2017-01-04|
+-----+---+-----+----------+
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the question lets say you have *search text* and *post count* as

```
val searchText = "F"
val postCount = 2
```

Then using the `searchText` in `filter` function you can get the *index of the row where the searchText matches*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val index = df.filter(col("label") === searchText).select("index").first().getAs[Int](0)
```

Final step is to *use the `postCount` with the `index` filtered to filter in your desired dataframe* as

```
val resultDF = df.filter(col("index") >= (index - postCount)  && col("index") <= (index + postCount))
```

which should give you

```
+-----+---+-----+----------+
|index|X  |label|date      |
+-----+---+-----+----------+
|4    |7  |D    |2017-01-04|
|5    |7  |E    |2017-01-04|
|6    |7  |F    |2017-01-04|
|7    |7  |G    |2017-01-04|
|8    |7  |H    |2017-01-04|
+-----+---+-----+----------+
```

Comment: How to repeat these statements for all the occurrences? assume i have 1000 records, with multiple F occurrences

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT index AS index_of_matched_search
   FROM mytable
   WHERE label='F')
WHERE abs(index - index_of_matched_search) <= 1000
```